# VBA - How run a Macro from another workbook without opening it?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to save all my VBA Project in a Excel workbook (or other type of file if possible) and then embbed it to run in another workbook. I've seen topics about it but only found ways to run the macros opening the first sheet.

I want to run a macro from a first workbook in a second one without opening the first workbook to do it. How can I do that?

Comment: When you say _Excel sheet_ do you mean the Excel file(workbook) as a whole, or individual sheets (worksheets) within the file?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Please write your description again. What did you meant by the "sheet" here?

Comment: I meant workbook. Edited my description

Answer (score 2):

Save the file with the macros as a xlam file and Excel can load them each time Excel opens.

You need to open File -> options -> add-ins.

At the bottom there is a button Go to (or something, I don't have English Excel on the current computer.)
Then add the file to the list by clicking Browse and finding the file you just saved as xlam file.

Comment: One points towards where you save the file... once you select the extensino of .xla or .xlam, the save location will change directing to the addin folder.  I believe the general consensus is to ensure you save to the XLSTART folder, rather than the addin folder.  For most computers, the location is: *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART*  (Note: i use that path for batch files when installing items on computers as to alleviate needing their full local path, such as user name).

Comment: Why XLSTART folder? I have never saved any of my add ins  there. What is the benefit of that versus in the add-in folder?

Comment: see: https://accessanalytic.com.au/xlstart-folder/ ; regarding general differences in XLSTART versus the AddIns folder, I am not versed enough to say explicitly why they both exist and for what purposes.  What I have noticed is, when having users across Excel 2010 through Office 365, that the XLSTART folder will load modules when Excel loads, allowing access of all macros, and allowing them to be added to the Quick Bar; this was the approach given to me when I had multiple users saving macros and the AddIn folder files would not display in the VBA Editor for >50% of my folks.

Comment: I read the reasons listed there and quite frankly, that is a good reason for me to not place anything in that folder. In my xlam files I always include code to both automatically install the xlam, meaning the end user only opens the file and he/she will be promoted to install yes/no. Then it's installed, no need to find a folder and manually place it there. And each xlam has code that looks for updates. Meaning I can upload a new version and all running this xlam will get a message there is a new version and the code will disable itself and install the new version.

Answer (score 2):

Two scenarios comes to mind:

1)  You have a second macro for personal use and can save it locally (save in: *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART*).  This will allow you to create quick-buttons for your macros, etc.  These types of macros open with Excel and will be separate VBA Projects inside of the default VBA editor.

2)  You have a network or drive that multiple users need to access, so each user has a macro in their file (.xlsm or .xlsb), where that internal macro reads  Application.Run "filepath\workbookname.xlsb!macro", which also allows you to call a private subroutine (note that you could use Call, but Application.Run will ensure that even Private macros are able to be accessed).  This shouldn't require the other workbook be open, though I have personally had one user whose computer always opens the other file, regardless.

---

**Edit:**

Third scenario (really 2b):

3)  You have files where you want to regularly access another file... you will follow a similar approach to point **2** where you make a macro to Application.Run, though you can save that macro in your XLSTART folder... this will allow you to have a source macro location where others may also want to access and utilize.  The *source* document would allow you to maintain 1 file for many users.

Answer (score 2):

Your answers were great! Great to know about XLSTART folder from @Cyril, but based on @Andreas answer I found my path.

The "problems" with adding an Add-In as @Andreas said, are cause my VBA Project would be avaliable on the VB Editor to every workbook on that computer, and to run my macros I'd have to use Application.Run("workbook.xlam!Macro").

Then I found References, which I have the same features, including I can delete my .xlam file to remove my code, and don't have the problems I mentioned above.

Adding my VBA .xlam file as an reference, it'll be avaliable only to that specific workbook and I can run my macro just like it was on the same workbook.

For general knowledge:

ADDING A REFERENCE:

1- Save your project as an Excel Add-In (.xlam file)

2- Open your target workbook, go to the Visual Basic Editor

3- Go to Tools > References > Browse... find your .xlam file and make sure it's checked.

4- Done! Now you'll see the project on the editor and can run your macros just like it was on the same workbook.

Comment: There are other, in my opinion better ways to limit the code to one or a few workbooks. You can make the code only run if activeworkbook is some name. Or limit it to the layout of a workbook, say A1 is "Date", B1 is something else then run the code else don't. I have one code that looks at the username logged in on the computer, if it's not me, then don't run. Whatever you can imagine is probably possible